# define property array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, defineproperty

I have initialized an object that I wish to add to dynamically. Specifically I want to add array of objects to this object. I have tried the below but neither work.. is there a way to do this correctly? The final output should be `object1.property1[0].value = 42` and `object1.property1[0].writable = false`.

```
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', '' );
object1.property1 = [{value: 42, writable: false}];


const object1 = {};
Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', [{value: 42, writable: false}] );
```

Comment: Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', { value: [{value: 42, writable: false}] });

Answer (score 2):

Try using `value` property from [descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) argument:

```js
const object1 = {};
Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {
  value: [{
    value: 42,
    writable: false
  }]
});

console.log(object1.property1[0].value);
console.log(object1.property1[0].writable);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The object descriptor must be declared as follow:**

```
{value: [{value: 42}], writable: false}
```

```js
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {value: [{value: 42}], writable: false});

console.log(object1.property1[0].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified you wanted to add an array of objects to the object, this solution is similar to other answers, but should demonstrate adding an array with more than one element:

```js
const obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'property', {
  value: [{
      value: 42,
      writable: false
    },
    {
      value: 55,
      writable: false
    }
  ]
});

console.log(obj.property[0].value);
console.log(obj.property[0].writable);

console.log(obj.property[1].value);
console.log(obj.property[1].writable);
```

Of course, your `writable` isn't going to do anything, since it'll be treated as just another property.  Due to the fact that your `property` is an array of objects (e.g., `[{...},{...}]`), what you may want to do is iterate over that array and freeze those objects:

```
obj.property.forEach(o=>Object.freeze(o))
obj.property[0].value=33;  // when frozen you won't be able to update the value
```